# Was the Moon an emissary for the Gods in greek mythology?

Tags: greek-language

I'm an astrology student and, in order to better understand the explanation for the meaning of certain phenomena, I'm investigating greek mythology.

Right now, I'm trying to understand why void moons. According to [this site](https://www.astrologyhub.com/void-of-course-moon/), it's because the Moon was an emissary of the planets:

> Consequently, one of the Moon’s jobs was to serve as emissary for all the other planets.  Since she produced no light of her own, she helped the other planets carry their light down to the physical plane. In so doing, heavenly will was made manifest.

However, I haven't been able to find any sources for this claim.

So, is this true? If so, could you point to any sources so I can continue researching on the topic?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I have never heard of this; traditionally, [Hermes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermes) was the messenger, even though it was possible for a god to send someone else than Hermes as a messenger. (Zeus does this a few times in the *Iliad*.)

Comment: [Selene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selene) (literally the embodiment of the moon, as opposed to Artemis, the Goddess of the Moon) appears extensively in Greek Mythology, but typically overshadowed by other more important characters. Her main duty is to drive the moon chariot, natch. Certainly the ancient Greeks (despite having a rudimentary knowledge of astronomy) would have been utterly unaware that the Moon shone by sunlight.

Comment: @Valorum [Your baseless "certainty" is mistaken](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/7890): Anaxagoras realised that the moon shone by sunlight in the 5th century BCE. Technically you might call [him](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaxagoras) an ancient Persian rather than ancient Greek, but he spent much of his life in Athens. (This is a bit tangential, though, as the question is about ancient Greek mythology rather than ancient Greek science.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I meant the ancient Greeks who created the god myths, not the ancient Greeks who lived 700 years later.